# Link to download file in Silverlight.

Tags: c#, silverlight, http, download

I'm not looking at `SaveFileDialog`

I want to be able to let user download file just like he clicked web page URL. My application is MVVM and I can't handle `Button_click` the way it is necessary to go around security limitations with 'SaveFileDialog'

When I download file in IE9 it just shows this little download bar on a bottom. How do I mimic this type of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get there if you can execute JavaScript as a result of clicking your Silverlight button.  Once you can execute JavaScript, you can use normal browser downloading techniques, even benefiting directly from IE9's download manager.

Try something like these:

- [Walkthrough: Calling JavaScript from Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)
- [Calling JavaScript functions from Silverlight 2](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=298)

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues in the past trying to have Silverlight invoke a standard download prompt via JavaScript (as though a user navigated to the download URL) due to various browser security issues or quirky behaviour.

In the end, I gave up and used the [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28VS.95%29.aspx) which basically works as though the user clicked a hyperlink and, thus far, works consistently across all browsers/security that I've tested.

Definitely not the best answer, and like I said, essentially came from "giving up".  I'd be interested to see a better method.

Answer (score 0):

HyperlinkButton is the only method that works as far as I am aware. We have tried various methods, but have eventually settled on HyperlinkButton mainly due to its ability to handle pop-up blockers correctly. Microsoft recommends this method.